# Why is the inverse Fourier transform another integral?

Tags: fourier-transform

I'm learning about the Fourier transform and have learned that the Fourier transform is
$$\hat{f}(\omega)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)e^{-2i\pi\omega x}dx$$
while the inverse transform is
$$f(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\hat{f}(\omega)e^{2i\pi\omega x}d\omega$$

Why is the inverse Fourier transform another integral? Isn't the opposite operation of an integral a derivative?

Comment: Integrals and derivatives being opposite to each other is the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, but you have to be really careful about what you mean. One of the FToC forms is: $\displaystyle \frac{d}{dx} \int_a^x f(t)\,dt = f(x)$. Notice that $x$ appears as the upper limit of the integral. In the Fourier transform, you integrate over the whole real line and the new variable is tucked away inside the integral instead. So the FToC analogy breaks down. [...]

Comment: [...] In general, Fourier transforms are integrals over some locally compact abelian topological group. Inverse Fourier transforms are integrals over the dual group. For the case of your LCA group being the reals, their dual group is themselves (takes a little bit of doing, but the argument isn't so bad). In the case of Fourier series, the Fourier transform is an integral over $[-\pi,\pi]$ and the dual group to $[-\pi,\pi]$ (mod $2\pi$) is the integers, so you get the Fourier series out of it. [...]

Comment: [...] I'd recommend reading a book on Fourier transforms, perhaps Stein and Shakarchi to see why the inverse should be an integral transform again. As Fourier series show, the inverse of an integral transform need not be an integral transform (at least not obviously so - it still is in that example, but your measure is the counting measure). There are some handwavy arguments you can find in texts like Boggess that motivate the fact that the inverse of the Fourier transform is again an integral transform. It is a good heuristic, but it is not particularly good math.

Comment: There are some bizarre cases like the Laplace transform: its inverse is an integral through the complex plane (similar with the Mellin transform). Even more bizarre are the fractional Fourier transform as well as the cubic and hexic transforms of Walters.

Comment: It's important to recall that $x$ is a real variable while $\omega$ is a complex variable. That alone excludes the derivative as providing the correct inverse. This is more about the chain rule and substitution, which starts with an integral and gives you a new one back in a new variable.